# How to use proxy in package.json in next.js?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, proxy, next.js

In `create-react-app`(s) it is possible to specify a proxy in the `package.json` like this:

```
{
    "name": "client",
    "version": "0.1.0",
    "private": true,
>>> "proxy": "http://localhost:5000", <<<
    "dependencies": {
            ...
    },
    "scripts": {
            ...
    },
    "eslintConfig": {
            ...
    },
    "browserslist": {
        "production": [
            ...
        ],
        "development": [
            ...
        ]
    }
}
```

Doing the same in a next.js app has no effect whatsoever. Is there a workaround? This would be especially useful when starting to decommission an old front-end but still using the backend.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try to use this package from npm to create a Node.js proxy for Express: [http-proxy-middleware](https://www.npmjs.com/package/http-proxy-middleware)

Then You can configure the target option to proxy requests to the correct domain:

```
const proxy = require('http-proxy-middleware')

app.use('/api', proxy({ target: 'http://localhost:5000', changeOrigin: true }));
```

Find similar package for next.js here: [next-http-proxy-middleware](https://www.npmjs.com/package/next-http-proxy-middleware)

Comment: Can you elaborate a little bit? I really do not want to change my current server/express app.

Comment: feels like this is still an alteration to the express app and not the next.js app. I meant I didn't want to do that.

Comment: Okay, see updated answer, link for next.js http-proxy-middleware package added.

Comment: https://nextjs.org/docs/advanced-features/multi-zones should that not be able to solve the problem?

Answer (score 2):

Another way is to use rewrites config:
https://nextjs.org/docs/api-reference/next.config.js/rewrites

```js
module.exports = {
    async rewrites() {
        return [
            {
                source: '/api/:slug*',
                destination: 'http://www.example.com/api/:slug*'
            },
        ]
    },
}
```